# android repo changelog

Tags: android, synchronization, android-source, repository, changelog

I have downloaded the android source repository with repo as documented. After that I'm synchronizing with 'repo sync' on a regular basis. That all works fine. However, I would like to obtain a list of recent changes between the different syncs. How can tat be done?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mike

Comment: if you can figure out a (git) command that prints the desired info for separate git repository you could try it with `repo forall -C <print log command>` and then do the sync.

Comment: that was the right hint. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [repo changelog subcmd](https://github.com/sagiben/Android).

You then can run the following commands:

```
repo sync -n
repo changelog --revisions='HEAD..aosp/master' 
repo sync
```